# How to login/register a user automatically when they send the form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, socket.io

I have a website that is running by Node.JS + Express + Socket.IO. I'm using MongoDB as database.

I have a page, in this page, when user clicks a button, I open up an Bootstrap Modal with register form to user. User can choose login form in this modal.

I have 3 events on Socket.IO Server and 3 events on Socket.IO Client too. These are,

```
Client                       Server
-----------------------------------
|                                 |
|       User Clicks Button        |
|------------------------------->>|
|                                 |
|  Server emits 'register' event  |
|<<-------------------------------|
|                                 |
|     Client catches 'register'   |
|  and opens register/login form  |
|    Fills the form and submits   |
| Client emits 'submit-register'  |
|             Event               |
|------------------------------->>|
|                                 |
|   Server checks the submitted   |
|form data and emits 'registered' |
|  event if user is successfully  |
| registered to database, if not  |
|  emits 'register-error' event   |
|<<-------------------------------|
|                                 |
|  User catches 'register-error'  |
|  or 'registered' events and a   |
| user opens it's session automa- |
|  tically without page refresh   |
|---------------------------------|
```

I want to do the bottom layer of communication. I don't want to user got any refreshing on page, but if there is no solution to this problem, It can be refreshed but It should open session.

I dont have any idea to do this, thanks. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the [passport-local](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/) strategy. This will allow you to set up user authentication through you server (node + express) - and when the auth is complete (either login or registration) - send a response back to your client.

On your client if you are using any kind of JS framework that has a promise based http request, you can wait for the response - and then choose what happens based the response your server provides the client.

Here is a front to back example using node, passport, vue, and axios:
https://blog.jscrambler.com/vue-js-authentication-system-with-node-js-backend